# Issue: Xcode 5 main window loses focus after Build/Run command

Tags: ios, xcode5

After clicking the Build/Run button on a project, the main window of Xcode loses focus. There is some configuration setting in order to avoid this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be configured in Xcode Preferences Behaviors.

Be aware that Apple has some bizarre ideas of what view should be displayed including sometimes displaying the code of another project in the build tab.

Comment: Ok, but what setting exactly? I tested some configurations (for example, Starts shows debugger with current) without success.

Comment: It is not easy and almost impossible to get exactly what you want.